# Powershell Start-Job with command

Tags: powershell, start-job

Trying to run `Start-Job` with following code but it doesn't seem to be working.  Not sure where am I going wrong with my understanding about the syntax:

```
 $ScriptBlock_test = {
        cmd /c "`"$mypath\tools\Parser.exe`" -f $some_file --csv `"$mypath\output`" --csvf out.csv"
    }

 Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock_test
```